# Python 2 and IPv6

Tags: python, ipv6

I'm trying to enable IPv6 in a Python 2 application and am running into trouble.  Whenever I try to bind to an IPv6 socket, a `socket.error: getsockaddrarg: bad family` exception is thrown.  I can reproduce the error simply by doing:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 12345))
```

This code works fine if I run in Python 3.  Unfortunately the script would need a significant porting effort to work in Python 3 and I'd rather not have to do that yet.

Is there something I need to do to get IPv6 working in Python 2 or am I S-O-L?

Details:
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71600, Oct 24 2009, 03:16:31) 
[GCC 4.4.1 [gcc-4_4-branch revision 150839]] on linux2
(it's the Python that's part of the standard openSUSE 11.2 install).

**Update**

After AndiDog helped me figure out that socket.AF_INET6 is defined even when IPv6 is not configured, I discovered `socket.has_ipv6`.  This is defined as a boolean and indicates whether Python was build with IPv6.

Comment: Python 2.6.1 running on FreeBSD works without issue.

Comment: Does it work with Python 3 on the *very same* operating system or another OS?

Comment: @AndiDog - yes, it works on Python 3 on the very same OS.  In a single shell (so identical environment), if I run `python2 ./script` I get the exception and then if I run `python3 ./script` I don't.

Comment: That's weird. Seems like Python wasn't configured with `--enable-ipv6`. It shouldn't be a OS problem because Python 3 works.

Comment: @Andidog - I would expect that if --enable-ipv6 was not used, the symbol socket.AF_INET6 would not be available.  Am I mistaken about that?

Comment: It seems that `socket.AF_INET6` is always available (if it is defined in the OS header files). Take a look at socketmodule.c, line ~4433.

Comment: BTW works on Debian lenny, Python 2.5.2

Comment: @Andidog - DOH!  My expectations led me astray.  If you turn your comments into an answer, I'll accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay here's the answer from the comments:

Seems like Python wasn't configured with `--enable-ipv6`.

It shouldn't be a OS problem because Python 3 works. Even if the OS doesn't have IPv6 support, it seems that `socket.AF_INET6` is always available (if it is defined in the OS header files). Cf. *socketmodule.c*, line 4433 (in current Python 2.6.4 source code).

Comment: Thanks.  I assumed that the presence of socket.AF_INET6 indicated that IPv6 was enabled.

Comment: This was very useful and worked for me.  But... where is the `--enable-ipv6` option documented?  It is not in the `README` at all.

Comment: For anyone like me who didn't see the `--enable-ipv6` configuration option anywhere, try doing `./configure --help`.  It shows more configure options than revealed in the `README` (which I suppose makes some sense in hindsight?).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like that particular Python was not compiled with IPv6 support.

In which case, you can download the source for that version and build yourself a compatible Python that will work.  You may even be able to do some editing in the Debian package and upgrade the system python.

Answer (score 2):

Works fine with 2.6.4 on my Mac (Mac OS X 10.5.8) -- and unfortunately I can't downgrade to 2.6.2 nor do I have any openSUSE around to check where the bug specifically comes from you. Could you try getting 2.6.4 and building from sources to see if the bug goes away, or check some openSUSE-specific bug tracker...?  At least we do know it's not a generic Python 2.6 bug (with the latest, bug-fixed version of 2.6, at least)...